# How use include method for ruby range values

Tags: ruby, range

I define some range variables

```
team_numbers = 1..11
defence_numbers = 2..5
center_numbers = 6..8
attack_numbers = 9..11
```

Why this code return false ?

```
puts (team_numbers === attack_numbers)
```

doesn't team_numbers range includes attack_numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see here [`Range#===`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)

> rng === obj → true or false
>
> Returns true if obj is an element of the range, false otherwise.

that's why the below results are expected :

```
(1..4) === 3 # => true
(1..4) === (1..3) # => false
(1..4) === (1..4) # => false
```

Saying that you got `false` as expected from the expression `puts (team_numbers === attack_numbers)`.